# How to bind both ways to a select in a Child Component - Blazor

Tags: blazor

Im trying to bind both ways to a select element in a Child Component. The Parent should be able to change the selected value of the Child Select, and the Child Select should callback to the parent when its changed so it can react to the new value. However I can seem to only pass down to the child, but not trigger the event up to the parent.

My Parent Component houses a Child Component that contains a select. The parent component looks like this:

```
        <SelectInput @bind-Value="Selected">
            @ChildContent
        </SelectInput>

@code{

    [Parameter]
    public string Selected { get; set; }
    [Parameter] 
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] 
    public EventCallback<string> SelectedChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task ValueChanged(string val)
    {
        await SelectedChanged.InvokeAsync(val);
    }
}
```

Both the ValueChanged and SelectedChanged are not being called. This is the issue I would like to solve.

The child component is the SelectInput Component:

```
        <select value="@Value"
            @onchange="OnValueChanged">
            @ChildContent
        </select>
        
        @code{
            [Parameter]
            public string Value { get; set; }
            [Parameter] 
            public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
        
            public async Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
            {
                Value = e.Value.ToString();
                await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
            }
        }
```

This child element is working and is invoking the ValueChanged Callback. However I cant catch the callback in the parent because its called already by the compiled code due to the bind-Value (which i need as it can also be changed outside this parent control. Again binding downwards is working, however i also need to bind upwards in this instance - or at least catch the event and propagate it upwards.
Any help will be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Parameter properties should not be mutated. They are used only for flowing data between components. For simplicity shake's I ignore this.

### GrandParent

```
@page "/"

Type a value USA ,France,etc.:
<input type="text" @bind="Selected" @bind:event="oninput" />

<ParentComponent @bind-Value="Selected"></ParentComponent>

@code{
     private string Selected { get; set; } = "Germany";
}
```

### ParentComponent.razor

```
<SelectInput @bind-Value="Value"></SelectInput>

@code{
    private string _value;

    [Parameter]
    public string Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if(_value != value)
            {
                _value = value;
                _ = ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_value);
            }
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

}
```

### SelectInput.razor

```
<select value="@Value" @onchange="OnValueChanged">
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    
</select>

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }


    public async Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Value = e.Value.ToString();
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @enet! Works a treat. Out of interest - this is part of a pagination control where the Page number can be changed either by a button set or by the select input (both seperate components) which is why im needing to mutate properties. How can we do it by simply propogating events upstream?

Comment: No, you shouldn't mutate parameter properties. NOTE: You can define local fields to hold the parameters' values passed from a parent component, and then mutate the values as much as you want. But don't change the values of the parameter properties themselves.  "How can we do it by simply propogating events upstream." This was what my code was showing... Note: When you have a parent-child relation, you may use component parameters with event call backs.

Comment: But when the relations go deeper (grandparent -> parent->child->grandchild), the best solution is to use services. I've a couple of answers in SO demonstrating it...Look for them